# change float value to time format for movie player,

Tags: iphone, ipad

iam using " moviePlayer.duration " to find the total time of video,but i get only float value,
how iam convert float value into time format "HH-MM-SS"

```
{

 duration=moviePlayer.duration;
}
```

Comment: what value are you getting in duration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method according to your requirement:

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(float)totalSeconds
{
   float seconds = totalSeconds % 60; 
   float minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60; 
   float hours = totalSeconds / 3600; 
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02f:%02f:%02f",hours, minutes, seconds]; 
}
```